# Maven replacing key value and filtering in one step

Tags: maven

Can maven (maven-antrun-plugin) run operations **in one profile**, operations like:

- replace key value in properties file,
- filter file with new keys.

What do I mean I have some.properties file with structure like

```
...
    
app.title=@app.title@

...
```

My profile in pom.xml looks like

```
<profile>
    <id>myApp</id>
    <properties>
            <app.title>App1</app.title>
            <app.title.dev1>App1</app.title.dev1>
            ...
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I know how to replace in properties file key value on @app.title.dev1@ but right now i end up with two files
one contains app.title=App1 and second (wtith diffreant name) app.title=@app.title.dev1@.
Is it possible to filter files in target directory or somehow do operations:

- replace key in properties file,
- filtering key in properties file

in one step?

I need two files because there are for different environments.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I had to add one more plugin with

```
<phase>process-resources</phase>
<goals>
<goal>resources</goal>
</goals>

...
```

befor plug responsible for overwriting key values.

Comment: If you need to do this your setup / pom is wrong....